# How do I use a "for loop" in my code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my javascript to output the education information into an HTML file. However, I am not very familiar with javascript, nor the for loop, but I know I must use it to get it to output the information. My question is, how would I incorporate the for loop into my code to get the schools section to output all the info into that section in HTML and get the online part to output into the online section in the HTML? This is the code that I have:

//education info

```
var education = {


"schools" : [
    {
        "name" : "John Brown University",
        "city" : "Siloam Springs, AR",
        "major" : ["Graphic Design"]
    },

    {
        "name" : "Shelton State Community College",
        "city" : "Tuscaloosa, AL",
        "degree" : "Associates",
        "major" : "Culinary Arts"
    }],


"online" : {
        "school" : "Udacity",
        "title" : "NanoDegree Front End Web Developer",
        "dates" : "Feb. 4 2016 - present",
        "url" : "https://www.udacity.com",
    }
};
```

//education append

```
education.display = function(){

for (var school in education.schools) {
$("#education").append(HTMLschoolStart);
 var name = HTMLschoolName.replace("%data%", education.schools[school].name);
 var city = HTMLschoolLocation.replace("%data%", education.schools[school].city);
 var major = HTMLschoolMajor.replace("%data%",education.schools[school].major);
$(".education-entry:last").append(name, city, major, degree);
}

$("#education").append(HTMLonlineClasses);
for (var course in education.online){
 var title = HTMLonlineTitle.replace("%data%", education.online[course].title);
 var school = HTMLonlineSchool.replace("%data%", education.online[course].school);
 var dates = HTMLonlineDates.replace("%data%", education.online[course].dates);
 var url = HTMLonlineURL.replace("%data%", education.online[course].url);
 $(".education-entry:last").append(title, school, dates, url);
 };
```

Comment: I have trouble to understand what you want to actually achieve. 1) The different `HTMLschool...` and `HTMLonline...` vars seem to be kind of templates: please show them. 2) You ask for how to incorporate `for()` loop in your code, but you're _already_ using it! Pleas explain...

Comment: Not clear what you asking...

Comment: Also, `education.online` isn't an array, you can't `for-loop` it. And `education.schools[school].major` can be both string *or* array, which will introduce some formatting problems...

Comment: I tried using this for loop, but its not working. I have very little knowledge of this stuff. But I attempted using this, but as it doesn't work, I figure I must have done it wrong. And for the education.online do I need to have it inside of [ ] ?

Comment: here is the HTML div i'm putting it into:

    `<div id="education" class='gray'>`
     `<h2>Education</h2> `
    `</div> `

the other js:

     `var HTMLschoolStart = '<div class="education-entry"></div>'; `
     `var HTMLschoolName = '<a href="#">%data%';`
     `var HTMLschoolDegree = ' -- %data%</a>';`
     `var HTMLschoolDates = '<div class="date-text">%data%</div>';`
     `var HTMLschoolLocation = '<div class="location-text">%data%</div>';`

     `var HTMLschoolMajor = '<em><br>Major: %data%</em>'; `

Comment: @JonathanColeLancaster Where's  HTMLonlineClasses defined?

Comment: @JonathanColeLancaster, yes, without additional `[ ]` this `for (var course in education.online)` will enumerate in `course` variable the `school, title, dates, url` fields of `education.online` object instead of actual courses, and that will lead to `education.online[course].title` (and others) being `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to populate your HTML with the data you have from your JSON, then you could try the following:

For "schools" you do need to loop:

```
//Loop Schools "Object"
for (var school in education.schools) {
 var name = education.schools[school].name;
 var city = education.schools[school].city;
 var major = education.schools[school].major;
$("#schools").append(name + city + major);
}
```

For "online", as it is directly defined object, you just get the value with the dot notation:

```
//Get Online "Object"
 var title = education.online.title;
 var school = education.online.school;
 var dates = education.online.dates;
 var url = education.online.url;
 $("#online").append(title, school, dates, url);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ce7b8fwf/3/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, generalize source data:

```
var education = {
    "schools" : [
        {
                "name" : "John Brown University",
                "city" : "Siloam Springs, AR",
                "major" : "Graphic Design"
        },

        {
                "name" : "Shelton State Community College",
                "city" : "Tuscaloosa, AL",
                "degree" : "Associates",
                "major" : "Culinary Arts"
        }
    ],


    "online" : [
        {
                "school" : "Udacity",
                "title" : "NanoDegree Front End Web Developer",
                "dates" : "Feb. 4 2016 - present",
                "url" : "https://www.udacity.com",
        }
    ],
```

Secondly, improve templating:

```
function template(code) {
    return function (data) {
        return code.replace(/\{\%([^\}\%]+)\%\}/g, function(m, property) { 
            return data[property] || '{%' + property + '%}'; 
        });
    };
}

...

var education = {
...

    templates: {
        school: template('\
        <div class="education-entry"> \
            <a href="#">{%name%} -- {%degree%}</a> \
            <div class="location-text">{%city%}</div> \
            <em><br>Major: {%major%}</em> \
        </div>'
        ),
        online: template('\
        <div class="education-entry-online"> \
            <a href="{%url%}">{%school%} - {%title%}</a> \
            <div class="date-text">{%dates%}</div> \
        </div>'
        )
    },
```

Thirdly, refactor display function:

```
    display: function() {
        var container = $("#education");

        for (var i in this.schools) {
            var school = this.schools[i];
            container.append(this.templates.school(school));
        }

        for (var i in this.online){
            var course = this.online[i];
            container.append(this.templates.online(course));
        };

    }
```

And combined:

```
function template(code) {
    return function (data) {
        return code.replace(/\{\%([^\}\%]+)\%\}/g, function(m, property) { 
            return data[property] || '{%' + property + '%}'; 
        });
    };
}

var education = {
    "schools" : [
        {
                "name" : "John Brown University",
                "city" : "Siloam Springs, AR",
                "major" : "Graphic Design"
        },

        {
                "name" : "Shelton State Community College",
                "city" : "Tuscaloosa, AL",
                "degree" : "Associates",
                "major" : "Culinary Arts"
        }
    ],


    "online" : [
        {
                "school" : "Udacity",
                "title" : "NanoDegree Front End Web Developer",
                "dates" : "Feb. 4 2016 - present",
                "url" : "https://www.udacity.com",
        }
    ],

    templates: {
        school: template('\
        <div class="education-entry"> \
            <a href="#">{%name%} -- {%degree%}</a> \
            <div class="location-text">{%city%}</div> \
            <em><br>Major: {%major%}</em> \
        </div>'
        ),
        online: template('\
        <div class="education-entry-online"> \
            <a href="{%url%}">{%school%} - {%title%}</a> \
            <div class="date-text">{%dates%}</div> \
        </div>'
        )
    },

    display: function() {
        var container = $("#education");

        for (var i in this.schools) {
            var school = this.schools[i];
            container.append(this.templates.school(school));
        }

        for (var i in this.online){
            var course = this.online[i];
            container.append(this.templates.online(course));
        };

    }
};

education.display();
```

*Tip: you can use `education.templates = { ...}` and `education.display =  function { ...}` instead of direct definition, of course.*

Comment: could you explain some of this a little bit? I am very new to javascript and I got a little lost going through this. For example, all the symbols after the return code.replace() ? And for the templates, is that something i need to add to the HTML or just right here in javascript, and should I delete the pre structured HTML ? sorry for all the questions, just trying to understand everything thats going on.